# Javascript to update percentage based on data entered into new cell of HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, percentage

I am trying to create a java script that will update a percentage of change in an HTML table based on new data being entered into different cells of that table. for example, if I have Row 1 "Design Data" set for 200, I enter 100 into "Data 1" I am hoping to see "% of Difference" for that row to change to 50%. If I then entered 150 into "Data 2" I would expect to se the "% of Difference" update to 75%

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
font-family: arial, sans-serif;
border-collapse: collapse;
width: 100%;
}

td, th {
border: 1px solid #dddddd;
text-align: left;
padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>HTML Table</h2>

<table>
<tr>
<th>Design Data</th>
<th>Data 1</th>
<th>Data 2</th>
<th>Data 3</th>
<th>Final Data</th>
<th>% of Difference</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="text" class="form-control each-test-data-field" data- 
field-attr="DD">
</td>
<td>
  <input type="text" class="form-control each-test-data-field" data-field-attr="D1">
  </td>
<td>
  <input type="text" class="form-control each-test-data-field" data-field-attr="D2">
  </td>
  <td>
  <input type="text" class="form-control each-test-data-field" data-field-attr="D3">
  <td>
  <input type="text" class="form-control each-test-data-field" data-field-attr="FD">
  </td>
  <td><span id="spanCalculatedPercentageToDesign">0%</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>
  <input type="text" class="form-control each-test-data-field" data-field-attr="DD">
  </td>
<td>
  <input type="text" class="form-control each-test-data-field" data-field-attr="D1">
  </td>
<td>
  <input type="text" class="form-control each-test-data-field" data-field-attr="D2">
  </td>
  <td>
  <input type="text" class="form-control each-test-data-field" data-field-attr="D3">
  <td>
  <input type="text" class="form-control each-test-data-field" data-field-attr="FD">
  </td>
  <td><span id="spanCalculatedPercentageToDesign">0%</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>
  <input type="text" class="form-control each-test-data-field" data-field-attr="DD">
  </td>
<td>
  <input type="text" class="form-control each-test-data-field" data-field-attr="D1">
  </td>
<td>
  <input type="text" class="form-control each-test-data-field" data-field-attr="D2">
  </td>
  <td>
  <input type="text" class="form-control each-test-data-field" data-field-attr="D3">
  <td>
  
  <input type="text" class="form-control each-test-data-field" data-field-attr="FD">
  </td>
  <td><span id="spanCalculatedPercentageToDesign">0%</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

here is the java script that currently is used to calculate the percentage of difference but only by Final Data and Design Data

```
var DD= 0, FD= 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var total = 0;

        for (k = 0; k < $('#testDataOuterDiv tbody tr.each-test-data').length; k++) {
            var elemVal = $('#testDataOuterDiv tbody tr.each-test-data:nth-child(' + (k + 1) + ') .each-test-data-field[data-field-attr=' + data[i].eachRow + ']').val();
            total += Number(elemVal) != NaN ? Number(elemVal) : 0;
            if (data[i].eachRow == 'Design Data') {
                DD+= Number(elemVal) != NaN ? Number(elemVal) : 0;
            } else if (data[i].eachRow == 'Final Data') {
                FD+= Number(elemVal) != NaN ? Number(elemVal) : 0;
            } 
        }


        if (data[i].eachRow == 'PreliminaryAK' || data[i].eachRow == 'PreliminaryFPM') {
            total = '';
        }

        $('#testDataOuterDiv tbody tr.test-data-total-row .test-data-total[data-field-attr=' + data[i].eachRow + ']').html(total);
    }

    $('#testDataOuterDiv tbody tr.test-data-total-row #spanCalculatedTotalPercentageToDesign').html("0%");
    if (DD!= 0) {
        $('#testDataOuterDiv tbody tr.test-data-total-row #spanCalculatedTotalPercentageToDesign').html(((FD/ DD) * 100).toFixed(0) + "%");
    }

    for (k = 0; k < $('#testDataOuterDiv tbody tr.each-test-data').length; k++) {
        $('#testDataOuterDiv tbody tr.each-test-data:nth-child(' + (k + 1) + ') #spanCalculatedPercentageToDesign').html("0%");
        var DD= $('#testDataOuterDiv tbody tr.each-test-data:nth-child(' + (k + 1) + ') .each-test-data-field[data-field-attr=Design Data]').val();
        var FD= $('#testDataOuterDiv tbody tr.each-test-data:nth-child(' + (k + 1) + ') .each-test-data-field[data-field-attr=Final Data]').val();
        if (Number(DD) != NaN && Number(DD) != 0 && Number(FD) != NaN) {
            $('#testDataOuterDiv tbody tr.each-test-data:nth-child(' + (k + 1) + ') #spanCalculatedPercentageToDesign').html(((Number(FD) / Number(DD)) * 100).toFixed(0) + "%");
            }
```

If I had to guess, the code that would need to be modified would be this section

```
if (Number(DD) != NaN && Number(DD) != 0 && Number(FD) != NaN)
```

my guess is something involving

```
if (Number(FD) != 0 && Number(D3) != 0 && Number(D2) != 0) 
{$('#testDataOuterDiv tbody tr.each-test-data:nth-child(' + (k + 1) + ') #spanCalculatedPercentageToDesign').html(((Number(D1) / Number(DD)) * 100).toFixed(0) + "%");}
```

Comment: Hi ! I have corrected the code highlighting (`> ` is for quotes, not code - check the editor help and [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) while you're at it.). I have seen the if and else if portion at the bottom didn't have closing `}` but I left the code as you provided it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I rewrote the question with simpler code examples and more info on what I am looking to do